# CSS in a SVG file transform scale moving right and down

Tags: html, css, svg

I am simply trying to make a Facebook icon in a SVG file grow in scale in its place. The problem is that it moves down and to the right. I want it to stay in position. Here is my code:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="800px"
     height="731.802px" viewBox="0 0 800 731.802" style="enable-background:new 0 0 800 731.802;" xml:space="preserve">

<style type="text/css" >
      <![CDATA[

        .facebook:hover {
           fill:#3b5998;
            stroke:#3b5998;
            pointer-events:all;

           opacity: 0.8;
           transition: all .3s ease-in-out;

               transition: transform 0.3s ease;
    transform-origin: center center;

            -webkit-transform: scale(1.3) translate(-8.6px, -8.6px);
 -moz-transform:    scale(1.3) translate(-8.6px, -8.6px);
 -ms-transform:     scale(1.3) translate(-8.6px, -8.6px);
  transform:        scale(1.3) translate(-8.6px, -8.6px);
}


      ]]>
</style>


<g id="Background">
    <g>
        <rect style="fill:#8CDDEA;" width="800" height="731.802"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="Objects">
    <g id="OBJECTS">

        <path id="facebook" class="facebook" style="#4D4D4D;" d="M334.979,143.357c0,1.308,0,7.15,0,7.15h-5.322v8.744h5.322v25.983h10.933
            v-25.983h7.336c0,0,0.687-4.193,1.02-8.777c-0.955,0-8.314,0-8.314,0s0-5.087,0-5.979c0-0.893,1.191-2.095,2.37-2.095
            c1.176,0,3.658,0,5.956,0c0-1.191,0-5.304,0-9.103c-3.068,0-6.559,0-8.099,0C334.709,133.298,334.979,142.05,334.979,143.357z"/>

    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you are trying to make it pulse (like a heartbeat), you will need to also translate the top/left corner (the origin) up and left by half the amount the image is scaled on each frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the icon to move, then just get rid of `translate(-8.6px, -8.6px)` in your transformations. By translating elements you move them around. Having set `transform-origin: center center`, scaling alone should give you the desired effect.

When looking at your code and the hovering effect, I suppose there might be an issue with your styles which could raise another question. If you want the hovering effect to behave symmetrically, i.e. have it being reverted when the mouse leaves the icon, you'll have to split your css definitions. You need to define the transition on the class `.facebook` along with the starting values for your icon. The target values where the transition will end will then be defined on `.facebook:hover`.

I put together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ce1got1t/) to demonstrate the effect.